# WPF MVVM Light Databinding a context menu to list view items

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, contextmenu, mvvm-light

I am fairly new to WPF MVVM so please have some patience. I have a `ListView` with a list of users and I want to add a ContextMenu to this ListView.  The ContextMenu should have the ability to edit whichever user you click on in the ListView.  I will show you the code I currently have, sketched out. I know it doesn't work at the moment, but the basic idea is I need the UserID from the ListView row AND the information that is selected in the ContextMenu.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
              <MenuItem Header="Test" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
              <Separator></Separator>
              <MenuItem Header="Status" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ObservableCollectionList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                   <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.DataContext.UpdateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
                        </Style>
                   </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
              </MenuItem>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>

        //users and stuff here

</ListView>
```

So my question is really two fold:

1. How do I attached the ContextMenu to individual ListView items.
2. How do I pass the ListViewItem object AND the ContextMenu selected object in to the ViewModel RelayCommand?

Or, is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATED CODE:**

I have tried both of the suggestions below but neither works.  I am going to supply the rest of the code that was already there, fully.  Keep in mind, this comes AFTER the  tag.

```
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemContainerTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" Opacity="0.5">
                                <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFDFE9F5" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                            <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Status}" FontStyle="Italic" Padding="0,0,0,3">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOnDuty}" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"  />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ItemContainerTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make use of `Styles` to inject `ContextMenu` on individual `ListViewItems`

this is how you can set the style

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}"
          SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.ListView.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="Test"
                                  Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}" />
                        <Separator></Separator>
                        <MenuItem Header="Status"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollectionList}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Command"
                                            Value="{Binding DataContext.UpdateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}" />
                                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter"
                                            Value="{Binding}" />
                                </Style>
                            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

unless a context menu is necessary on the main ListView you may remove `ListView.ContextMenu`

you may need to do the adjustments as needed as I did it based on some assumptions about the view model.

Comment: I tried this and it says: BindingExpression path error: 'ListView' property not found on 'object'.  I will supply more code up top.

Comment: I ended up setting the ItemSource for the observable collection list to findancestor on the views parent control and reached into the datacontext from there and it worked properly.  I wouldn't have figured it out if it weren't for your guidance here.  Thank you.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you! at the same time do please accept my apologies for not being able to assist you for the binding error you faced (due to time zone difference). anyways happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just another way of doing things.
If you don't want the `ContextMenu` to be in your `ListView` definition you could use this

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.ListView.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
     <MenuItem Header="Test" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}" />
     <Separator></Separator>
     <MenuItem Header="Status" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollectionList}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name">
         <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
              <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                   <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.UpdateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}" />
                   <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
              </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}"
      SelectionMode="Single">
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}">
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Although personally I prefer to use

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
```

This way you can easily switch between different ContextMenus.

Comment: Do you meen put the Context menu declaration  in between style tags like: <ListView.ItemContainerStyle> <Style targettype="x:type listviewitem" value="{staticresource contextmenu}" />   ??

Comment: @user1296981 I meant you out the declaration of the `ContextMenu` in your `Window.Resources` or `UserControl.Resources`. Then you can use which ever `ContextMenu` you have declared in there by using `Style` in your `ListView` or whichever Control you're using to display. Hope that makes sense.